# Suggested edit rejected by community, why?

Tags: discussion, editing

Recently one of my edit suggestion on [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12152/5486) was rejected by the [Community♦](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) stating

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

Here is the [Revision history.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11260)

My question is : I edited that question and corrected the grammar in the question and spelling mistakes. But why my edit was rejected? Any specific things I missed in my edit or is it mistake on the part of community user (bot).

Comment: See this Meta answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/236254 Basically Community rejecting an edit suggestion means some (human) user chose the "reject and edit" option when reviewing the edit suggestion.