# On what criteria does the Community accept a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, community-user

The suggested edit by an Anonymous User to [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13806/3500) for the question [Does Anushasan Parva, chapter 88 of the Mahabharata, allow cow sacrifice?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8958/3500) got approved by Community.

[This question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/556/3500) on meta suggests Community bot could be human sometimes.  Clearly that edit was meaningless.

So, on what criteria did Community accept that edit?

[image]

Comment: Answer is in [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/511/76), refer 5th linked meta post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/260388):

> #### A reviewer either improves an edit, or rejects and replaces it with a different edit
>
> When one is reviewing suggested edits, there are five available
> buttons, two of  which allow the reviewer to edit the post themselves:
>
> [image: five buttons]
>
> If the reviewer chooses Improve Edit and submits their improved form
> of it, the suggested edit is approved by Community ♦ (and immediately
> replaced by the improved one). If the reviewer chooses Reject and
> Edit, Community ♦ rejects the suggestion.

Also visit [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/260388):

> One of the reviewers has chosen the option to "Improve" your suggested edit. In that case, depending on whether the reviewer has chosen to deem your suggested edit helpful, the Community user will approve or reject your edit.

And [Why are my suggested edits here approved by Community♦?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86630/260388) may be a straight to your question.